# Evolve pre order content not found

Tags: evolve

So one of my friends pre ordered Evolve for PC and was hoping he was going to get the Behemoth. However, the Behemoth was nowhere to be seen (ironic pun lol). How do you get the Behemoth if you pre ordered Evolve for PC?

Comment: Hi, David.  I've removed your secondary, unrelated question.  Please ask that as a separate question, as it has nothing to do with the rest of this one.

Comment: did your friend get a code to use? (it may be a separate code from the game's download code). my experience with Pre-orders with DLC for consoles is that more often than not you are given a voucher codes to download the DLC for free regardless if it is listed on the store or not (as was the case with Final Fantasy XIII-2 Pre-order in the begining)

Comment: @Memor-X There aren't separate preorder codes for Evolve. It's all included with the game code.

Answer (score 1):

The Behemoth isn't released just yet. It will be in the Monster expansion pack DLC. Which will be out in the Spring of 2015, according to the Wiki: http://evolve.wikia.com/wiki/Behemoth

Edit: The behemoth has finally come out for the PC on the 31th of March. Also together with 4 new hunters to hunt him with (If you got the hunting season pass)